# Restrict DateTime with a minimum date and time (not fall below 00:00)

Tags: c#, datetime

I am using `DateTime` and it's methods like `DateTime.AddMinutes` etc.

Is there a way to make DateTime throw an Exception when adding a negative number of minutes/seconds etc that make the time fall beneath 00:00 and not turn the time to 23:59?

Comment: No. Create your own methods that enforce the semantics you want.

Comment: No, the `DateTime` struct doesn't support restrictions like that. The methods like `AddMinutes` aren't even aware of when you change the time to cross a date boundary. The internal value is just a `long` that represents 1/10000 seconds since 0001-01-01. When you add minutes, that is just translated into 1/10000 seconds and added to the internal value. Wrap the `DateTime` in a class or a struct and have methods that does the checks that you need.

Comment: @Guffa - Actually, 1/10000000.  :)

Answer (score 1):

**At Domain Model Level**

At the domain model you could a Decorator/Wrapper class. Just use a class that has a private DateTime object and pass through every method of that object that remains unaltered and implement those that are altered, essentially just by writing:

```
public bool Equals(DateTime dt){
    return this.dateTime.Equals(DateTime dt);
}
```

There are however a couple of issues with this:

- In the above example you might want to compare your DateTime object with itself, but that won't be possible.
- DateTime has certain attributes eg. its serializable that you may lose until adding a fair bit of time to this.

**At Controller Level**

Assuming you are implementing this in an applicatino with MVC setup, you probably have some validation within your controller. That should be able to handle these cases.
I'd recommend this approach, as you can reject any case where the Date part of the datetime does not match or is less than the original date.

Comment: Is this suggestion not a bit over complicated since he may only be using this method once?

Comment: I'd think it's best practice. Also your approach (which may well fit into a Validation with a little adjustment) would only cover the 'AddMinutes' method but not other methods such as AddHours, AddDays which were covered in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a extension method like so:

```
    public static class MyDateTimeChecker
    {
        public static bool CheckTime(this DateTime dt, int minutes)
        {
            if (dt.Day > dt.AddMinutes(minutes).Day)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }
    }
```

I placed Day since in your question you wanted to know if it would fall bellow 00:00 or back to the previous day at 23:59,so this is one way to go.
Then in your code you can use it like this:

```
   DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
   if(dt.CheckTime(-1440))
   {
      //if true your negative number was in range
      //so use it if you like.
   }
   else
   }
      //oops too much
   }
```

Comment: Is it not risky to use the DateTime.Day property? You could deduct something like `dt.AddMinutes(-daysOfLastMonth * 24 * 60)` and still not fall foul even though you're moving to the previous month. I'd use the `Date` property instead.

Comment: Yes your absolutely right i was going originaly to date but since OP by the context of the question is only interested in day-to-previousday datetime variables i opted with day.i can change that or change the method name to something like CheckIsSameDay.